# How to print result from java controller class in dialog box or pop up window JSP page?

Tags: javascript, java, model-view-controller

I have a jsp page that takes AppName as input.
The app name is selected by user through drop down.
The controller clas then validates AppName, whether it exists or not.
If yes, It returns its admin name and email.
I want to print admin name and email in a dialog box/pop up window.
How to print result from java controller class in dialog box or pop up window JSP page ?

Comment: Can you post  the code what have you done so far?

Comment: Sharing a code with post is always a good option to make it understandable